# keep only numbers from string except for decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, replace, slice, indexof

I'd like to get only the percent of MyFruit in a string. 
But before with my variable CleanString, I'd like to keep only numbers from string except the separator ("." or ",") for the decimal.
I don't know why it doesn't work very well. Example, if there's no "banana"...
I would like to get the result "1,2" if there is banana with percent.

```js
var MyFruitSalad = "orange* 1,5%, bananaX, banana,BaNana_1,2%, apple_5 %, pineapple:3.5%";
var MyFruit = "banana";
var PercentMyFruit = MyFruitSalad.slice(MyFruitSalad.indexOf(MyFruit) + MyFruit.length).split('%').shift();

var CleanString = PercentMyFruit.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
console.log(CleanString);
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Post an example of what you want to see as the result.

Comment: Important to clarify, I think where you are from comma "," is used for decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search in a lower case string the lower case word and take the index until the percent sign. Then replace the unwanted characters.

[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) works case sensitive.

```js
function getValue(string, word) {
    var index = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()),
        part = string.slice(index + word.length, string.indexOf('%', index));

    return index === -1
        ? 'no ' + word + ' found!'        // or throw an exception
        : part.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
}

console.log(getValue("orange* 1,5%, BaNana_1,2%, apple_5 %, pineapple:3.5%", "banana"));
console.log(getValue("orange* 1,5%, BaNana_1,2%, apple_5 %, pineapple:3.5%", "foo"));
```

Comment: It doesn't work if there's not "banana" in var "salad". The result is always "1,"5